# Using Union for function arg throwing type errors

Tags: typescript

I have the following types that are setup to handle 2 different form submissions with 2 different objects as the argument in a function.

```js
interface FormValues {
  firstNames: string;
  middleNames: string;
  surname: string;
}

interface PasswordFormValues {
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
}

type FormSubmit = (values: FormValues | PasswordFormValues) => Promise<void>

interface ProfileFormProps {
  onFormSubmit: (values: FormValues | PasswordFormValues) => Promise<void>;
}
```

However trying it pass in either type for the argument in the function using the `FormSubmit` type, I get the following Type error.

```
Type '(values: PasswordFormValues) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(values: FormValues | PasswordFormValues) => Promise<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
    Type 'FormValues | PasswordFormValues' is not assignable to type 'PasswordFormValues'.
      Type 'FormValues' is missing the following properties from type 'PasswordFormValues': password, confirmPassword
```

```js
const formValues: FormValues = {
  firstNames: 'Name',
  middleNames: '',
  surname: 'Surname'
};

const passwordFormValues: PasswordFormValues = {
  password: 'password',
  confirmPassword: 'password'
};

const updatePassword = async (values: PasswordFormValues) => {};

const props: ProfileFormProps = {
  onFormSubmit: updatePassword
}
```

How can I pass either object as the argument in a function using the `FormSubmit` type?

I have a [TypeScript Playground URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#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) with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your handler to take *either* a handler for a `FormValues` or a `PasswordFormValues`:

```js
interface ProfileFormProps {
  onFormSubmit: ((values: FormValues) => Promise<void>) | ((values: PasswordFormValues) => Promise<void>);
}
```

That said, this opens you up to someone configuring a form that only *produces* `FormValues` and providing an `onFormSubmit` that only **consumes** `PasswordFormValues`.  Ideally you'd use correlated union types *a la* Joe Calzaretta's [microsoft/typescript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)